# Convention for tornado template file naming?

Tags: naming-conventions, tornado

My team is using Tornado web server and the included [Tornado template language](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/template.html).

Currently we, like the examples, use '.html' for Tornado template files. Which irks me somewhat, as Tornado templates are not pure HTML.

Eg, Django generally uses .dtml, Mustache uses .mustache.

Is there a similar convention for Tornado template files? If so, what is it?

Comment: Where you took information about that django uses .dtml? It looks more like zope way.

Comment: @Nikolay I see you're right - the official Django docs use .HTML for template files too (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system). I think .dtml comes from various text editors.

Comment: DOES Tornado have any convention anybody ?